# Force a backgrounded complex task to fg itself?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, job-control

I will often run a simple monitoring task like the following:

```
(sleep 600 && ls -lh /path/to/files)&
```

Is it possible to have the process de-background itself part way in? For example, to grab the job id into `$jobid` (or similar), and then when the `sleep` finishes, do an `fg $jobid`?

This may require some more complex bash-fu, I am aware, but any solutions would be nice to see (especially if it's possible to only `fg` if there is no other interactive process running).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-interactive script has job control turned off by default, but you may enable it with `set -m` or `set -o monitor`. Here's an example script:

```
# turn on job control
set -o monitor

# start a background task
( sleep 10 && echo "slept 10 seconds" ) &

# do something else
sleep 5
echo "slept 5 seconds"

# bring the background task into the foreground
fg

echo "done"
```

Here's its output when run with tracing (`bash -x script.sh`):

```
+ set -o monitor
+ sleep 5
+ sleep 10
+ echo 'slept 5 seconds'
slept 5 seconds
+ fg
( sleep 10 && echo "slept 10 seconds" )
+ echo 'slept 10 seconds'
slept 10 seconds
+ echo done
done
```